# How to build Data Access Layer independent of Schema Changes

Tags: c#

We would like to know is there any pattern in Data access layer which works perfectly with change in schema in C#.NET. I Would like to build Data access layer which is schema agnostic

Comment: Do you mean schema as in database namespace-like construct (e.g. foo.my_table where foo is the schema) or schema as in the structure of your tables/indexes/etc? If the latter, you can only minimize the impact, not eliminate it.

Comment: Any parameter you extract from data accessing procedure can be treated as schema. You're saying "I would like to write function which works for all values of incoming parameter"

Comment: You could try a Generic Repository, but it's widely regarded as an anti-pattern.  At the end of the day, you still have to specify the names of tables and fields or entities and properties.

Comment: We are building services for BLL and DAL. If there is change in Table Schema like column addition or deletion , change in type of column, we will have to change entity,If there is change in entity , we need to deploy both DAL and BLL. Instead we would like to have DAL Schema independent like C# Expando Objects and return to BLL . BLl will transform dynamic objects to actual entity, here we will deploy only BLL, there is no change in DAL.